# How to delete data from MongoDB without slowing it down to a halt?

Tags: mongodb, performance

Everytime we delete larger amounts of data from our MongoDB using `collection.remove()`, this makes the database so slow that eventually our web servers go down. I believe this is because the remove operation locks the collection for longer periods of time.

We have a query that gives us all the documents we want to delete. However the query does not include a date/time field, so we can't use a TTL index.

Is there a way to remove data in a `nice` way, freeing the lock from time to time?

Comment: My hacky solution: Write a program that queries the IDs of all documents you want to delete, store them in an array / list. Then fire a remove command for each one of them. However this is very slow

Comment: Is this an expiration thingy? Do the documents have a date field of some sort?

Comment: Unfortunatly they don't, otherwise I would use a TTL index. It's more of a migration thingy.

Comment: Ongoing? That sound more like a problem with your data model than with MongoDB. I need more info on that, like sample documents, deletion triggers and such. In general, no, there isn't a way of throttling removes. You could use bulk operations, but it sounds like this is a way of treating the symptoms, not the cause of the problem.

Comment: You can call it a problem with our data model, but I would prefer to say our requirements changed, and we want to adopt our data model. For this we need to delete some obsolete documents (about 12 million). We have a query that gives us these 12 million documents, but the query does not involve a date/time field. How can I use bulk operations for this kind of scenario? I looked at it, but I couldn't figure out how to use it from the documentation.

Comment: What is the version  of MongoDB? What kind of deployment is it (standalone/replica-set/sharded cluster)? Are you using some tool like `mongo` shell _or_ an application program using a driver? What kind of hardware is the db deployed on? What operations go on the deployment when you are trying to delete? Please provide some of this information - as all or some of these can affect performance.

Comment: This was years ago, I don't remember. Haven't used MongoDB much since then.

Answer (score 42):

## Using bulk operations

Bulk operations *might* be of help here. An unordered `bulk.find(queryDoc).remove()` basically is a version of `db.collection.remove(queryDoc)` optimized for large numbers of operations. It's usage is pretty straightforward:

```js
var bulk = db.yourCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
bulk.find(yourQuery).remove()
bulk.execute()
```

Please see [Bulk.find().remove() in the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.remove/#bulk-find-remove) for details.

The idea behind this approach is not to speed up the removal, but to produce less load. In my tests, the load was reduced by half and took slightly less time than a `db.collection.remove(query)`.

## Creating an index

However, a remove operations should not stale your instance to a point of freezing. I tested the removal of 12M documents on my 5 year old MacBook and while it put some load on it, it was far away from freezing, and took some 10 minutes. However, the field I used to query was indexed.

This leads me to the conclusion that probably you might be experiencing a collection scan. If I am right, here is what happens: Your query contains fields or a combination of fields not contained in an index or for which an index intersection can not be constructed. This forces the mongod in question to find, access and read those fields *for each and every document in the database* ***from disk***.

So, it might be helpful to create an index containing each field in your query in background prior to the remove operation, however counterintuitive this is.

```
db.collection.createIndex(
  {firstFieldYouQueryBy:1,...,NthFieldYouQueryBy:1},
  {background:true}
)
```

Albeit this operation will be done in background, the shell will block.
This might take a while. You can see the status by opening a second shell and use:

```
db.currentOp()
```

(You'll have to search a bit).

When the index is created (which you can check by using `db.collection.getIndices()`), your removal operations should be more efficient and hence faster. After the mass removal is done, you can of course delete the index, if not needed otherwise.

With an index, your prevent a collection scan, thereby speeding up the removal considerably.

## Combining both approaches

It should be obvious that it makes sense to create the index first and issue the bulk command after the index is ready.

Comment: Hey Markus, thanks for your detailed answer! You are right, the query we have does not use an index. However, creating an index on our live replica set is also a problem, it also freezes our web application servers :-(. So we can't just create an index, we have to remove each node from the replica set one by one, create the index offline, and reattach it to the replica set. This seems a lot of effort, just to delete some documents. Also this involves a stepdown and an election of a new primary, which means the database is effectively down for some seconds.

Comment: @BastianVoigt Contacted you via Skype, I think there is need to talk.

Comment: Sorry I stopped using Skype since they still don't have a 64-bit linux version. E-Mail me at post bei bastian minus, voigt punkt de.

Comment: Could someone explain how exactly the bulk operations manage to reduce the server load? From the documentation it's not quite clear to me...

Comment: Hey I tried this approach, 1st created an index on the column where I have the timestamp, then ran the bulk remove query. but it removed 50 to 80 records per second. The total collection size is 1TB

Comment: @BhuvaneshHard to say what is going on without any further insights. I suggest you ask a question yourself, in case you think it is very different from this.

Comment: This is a great solution, but for practical purposes, people using this shall be aware of choosing between not writing data matching the filter in a query or accepting to delete such written documents during the time this query is executed. [Here is a lesson learned.](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/would-bulk-remove-delete-documents-that-match-the-query-while-its-in-progress/112503/4?u=naman)

Comment: @Naman The circumstances you described seem... weird. I have to dig deeper into that. Can you provide the query and the collection metadata, as well as some sample documents?

Comment: The query I ran was alike `var bulk = db.getCollection('my_collection').initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
bulk.find( {"docId":{"$gte": 400, "$lte": 500}}).remove()
bulk.execute()`. The number of documents matching this query before I ran this was ~800000 and then while this took time to execute. In this window, there were 10 more documents inserted in the collection with `docId==435`, they were deleted as well. If you insert those documents after this query, they would remain as is. That's the difference I was highlighting. To reproduce the scenario, you need to create a good number of documents.

Comment: "In new code, use `Bulk.find.delete()` instead of `Bulk.find.remove()`." https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.remove/#mongodb-method-Bulk.find.remove