# Mongo bulkWrite() on a single Model

Tags: java, mongodb

Reading the mongo [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/Bulk.find.remove/) and on the stackoverflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188586/deletion-of-1-million-records-with-bulkwrite-deletemanymodel-taking-longer-tim), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33164008/410624), I can not be certain if the bulkWrite() on a single Model also does bulk operations or is it treated the same as a simple query.

Lets say I want to remove 5M records without straining the production environment too much, the query for the removal is very straight forward i.e.  `deleteQuery.field("user").equal(sysUser.getId())`.

Now does it make any difference if I do the following:

```
List<WriteModel<Document>> deleteManyModel = new ArrayList<>();
deleteManyModel.add(new DeleteManyModel<>(new Document("user", user.getId())));
getCollection().bulkWrite(deleteManyModel);
```

Compared to:

```
getCollection().deleteMany(eq("user", user.getId()));
```

Comment: deleteMany and delete using bulkWrite both send one command to the database server - where each document is deleted based upon the query condition. They are the same. Bulk write supports different kind of operations (CUD of CRUD) as a single command.

Comment: Can you provide any proof to that statement? Are those stackoverflow links my incorrect interpretation? I did notice that there are very little changes while running both approaches on a localhost, which confirms your statement in a way.